# Screen sharing between a MacBook Pro and an iMac

Tags: macbook-pro, imac

I have an iMac 21.5" and a MacBook pro. How can I connect the macbook pro to use the iMac's screen?

Comment: Which models, when were they purchased? As far as I know only the 27" can handle it, but if you can specify which one it might make it easier to work out.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a mini display to mini display chord; one end goes in your iMac & the other end goes into your MacBpook Pro

This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YBFKDH5FhQ) shows exactly what you need & how to do it

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the screen sharing feature in OS X - it's really easy to use. I've written an easy to follow tutorial about how to use it:

http://machow2.com/how-to-share-screen-on-mac/

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.